# What should be the name of sitemap file while submitting to Google Webmasters?

Tags: sitemap, google-search-console

I just want to know while submitting a sitemap file to Google webmasters, what should be the name of the file?

Is it necessary to keep the sitemap filename as `sitemap.xml` or can I use any custom name for the file?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde FYI and for anyone finding this question on Google, I asked a somewhat related question over on the webmasters SE since this is the first result when searching for this question on Google. You can view it here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102791/does-name-of-sitemap-file-that-wordpress-generates-matter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not obligatory. you can use any name for your sitemap and you can place it anywhere.

but it is just for Google. if you want to all of search engines find your sitemap, you should name it "sitemap.xml" and place it in your root directory.

Comment: You can tell all robots (that care to listen) where to find it by adding a line like this to your robots.txt `Sitemap: http://www.example.com/my-custom-sitemap.xml`